# Wedge sum of contractible spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $\vee_i U_i$ be the wedge sum of a set of based spaces $(U_i,x_i)$. Suppose each $U_i$ is a contractible neighborhood of $x_i$, then I want to prove that $\vee_i U_i$ is also contractible. (J. P. May mentions this statement in Section 2.8 of his book A Concise Course in Algebraic Topology)

My attempt: Suppose $F_i: c_{x_i} \simeq id_{U_i}$ are homotopies, where $c_{x_i}: U_i \to U_i$ is the constant map with value $x_i$. I tried to construct a homotpy $F$ between $c_x:\vee_i U_i \to \vee_i U_i$ and $id_{\vee_i U_i}$ via $F|_{U_i}=F_i$, where $x$ is the homotopy class of $x_i$. But the problem is that for fixed $t \in [0,1]$, $F_i(x_i, t)$ are different in general, so $F$ is not well-defined at $x$.

Q: How to explicitly contruct a homotopy between $c_x$ and $id_{\vee_i U_i}$?

Comment: So a contractible space $X$ is contractible "to any point" of $X$.  As well, on a wedge sum a function is continuous iff its restriction to each wedge is continuous and the restrictions agree on the base point.  Put these two together and the result is basically immediate; are either of these results what you are wanting, or it is not clear how putting them together gets your result?

Comment: @JohnSamples I don't see how can the restrictions agree on the base point, because $F_i(x_i, t)=x_i$ need not be always true as I know.

Comment: I think I understand your hang-up; you're worried about a situation like this: One of the wedge factors $X$ is contractible, but every contraction "moves the desired based point" around, right?  Well that's actually fine!  Just formally define the function on the disjoint sum of the wedges separately, then factor through the quotient map that wedges them!  Basically view each wedge as sliding around on the basepoint, but your function is constantly adjusting it back where it needs to be as you do your contraction.  The continuity will be by def.

Comment: @JohnSamples: Sorry, I am not sure I understand your intuitive proof. It would be better if you could write down an explicit construction for such a homotopy as an answer, thx.

Comment: I mean, the wedging is a quotient map.  You know the properties of quotient maps?  Especially that continuous maps factor through them?  If I post an answer it will be like two lines and not be any more explanatory.  Basically this is just a quotient map question; just start writing down a proof attempt using this fact and it'll fall right out.  Quotient at each time $t$ and they'll glue together by definition!

Comment: @JohnSamples: You mean the universal property of quotient maps? Yes, I know it. But I cannot see how this works, because in general $F_i(x_i, t) \neq F_j(x_j, t)$ for distinct $i, j$, the premise of the universal property is not valid in this case.

Comment: You quotient along the image of those points under the homotopy, they're not 'rigidly stuck' like that.  You're thinking of the wedge sum too concretely.  Do your homotopies in the disjoint union and have the "wedge point" vary along with the homotopies.  Use the UMP for quotients to show that this commutes with the map you're defining on your original wedge sum.

Comment: @JohnSamples: Thanks for the comments, but I still prefer a mathematically rigorous proof, that would be easier for me to understand.

Comment: The Griffiths twin cone might be something interesting to think about.

Comment: I assume when he says "contractible with base points" he means that each preimage of the wedge point has a contractible neighborhood.  At which point it's just SVK, but I think he's asking to "see what it looks like".  Tbh I'm not even sure what he's asking at this point; possibly he's asking us to prove something that isn't even true!

Comment: @JHF: Thanks, that is exactly what I want!

Comment: Where precisely does May claim that?

Comment: @PaulFrost: The first proposition in Chapter 2 Section 8

Answer (score 1):

The statement is wrong, the Griffiths Twin Cone is a counterexample, as suggested by JHK in the comment above. So when May says $U_i$ is a contractible neighborhood of $x_i$, I guess he means $x_i$ is a strong deformation retraction of its open neighborhood $U_i$.

Comment: The usual way to express that is that the  $(U_i,x)$ are *pointed contractible*.